# SQL code to display counts() of value retrieved from another column

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have three tables (these are the relevant columns):

```
Table1
bookingid, person, role


Table2
bookingid, projectid


Table3
projectid, project, numberofrole1, numberofrole2
```

Table1.role can take two values: "role1" or "role2".

What I want to do is to show which projects *don't* have the correct number of roles in Table1. The number of roles there there should be for each role is in Table3.

For example, if Table1 contains these three rows:

```
bookingid, person, role
7, Tim, role1
7, Bob, role1,
7, Charles, role2
```

and Table2

```
bookingid, projectid
7, 1
```

and Table3

```
projectid, project, numberofrole1, numberofrole2
1, Test1, 2, 2
```

I would like the results to show that there are not the correct number of *role2s* for project *Test1*.

To be honest, something like this is a bit beyond my ability, so I'm open to suggestions on the best way to do this. I'm using sqlite and php (it's only a small project). I suppose I could do something with the php at the end once I've got my results, but I wondered if there was a better way to do it with sqlite.

I started by doing something like this:

```
SELECT project, COUNT(numberofrole1) as "Role"
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
USING (projectid)
JOIN Table3
USING (bookingid)
WHERE role="role1"
GROUP BY project
```

But I can't work out how to compare the value returned as "Role" with the value got from numberofrole1

Any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Select * From Table3 t3
Where (Select Count(*) From Table1 t1r1
          Join Table2 t2r1 On t2r1.bookingid = t1r1.bookingid
       Where t2r1.projectid = t3.ProjectId
          And role = 'role1') <>  numberofrole1 
     Or
     (Select Count(*) From Table1 t1r2
          Join Table2 t2r2 On t2r2.bookingid = t1r2.bookingid
       Where t2r2.projectid = t3.ProjectId
          And role = 'role2') <>  numberofrole2
```

or even better, if it works... (try it)

```
Select * From Table3 t3
Where Exists 
      (Select * From Table1 t1r1
          Join Table2 t2r1 
               On t2r1.bookingid = t1r1.bookingid
       Where t2r1.projectid = t3.ProjectId
       Group By Role
       Having Sum(Case Role When 'role1' Then 1 Else 0 End) 
                              = t3.numberofrole1
          And Sum(Case Role When 'role2' Then 1 Else 0 End)  
                              = t3.numberofrole2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    projectid, 
    role,
    CASE WHEN role = 'role2' THEN numberofrole2 DEFAULT numberofrole1 END numRequired,
    COUNT(*) numPresent
  FROM Table1 
  JOIN Table2 ON Table1.bookingid = Table2.bookingid
  JOIN Table3 ON Table2.projectid = Table3.projectid
  GROUP BY projectid, role
)
WHERE numRequired > numPresent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT
    projectid, 
    numberofrole1,
    numberofrole2,
    SUM(role='role1') as actual_numberofrole1,
    SUM(role='role2') as actual_numberofrole2
FROM table3
JOIN table2
    USING (projectid)
JOIN table1
    USING (bookingid)
GROUP BY projectid
HAVING numberofrole1 <> actual_numberofrole1
    OR numberofrole2 <> actual_numberofrole2
```